# FB.getLoginStatus is returning status 'unknown' even when the user is logged in

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have third party cookies enabled so that's not the problem. I'm using google Chrome, facebook javascript SDk `version 2.5`, everything is working the first time when I login, but when I log out and try to log back in, it's returning `status: 'unknown'`

Comment: Might be the same issue as here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1657864107810379/

Comment: In my case i switched the allowed URI's and got this message. Deleting the cookies solved the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following code after logout to resolve the issue:

```
document.cookie.split(";").forEach(function(c) {
    document.cookie = c.replace(/^ +/, "").replace(/=.*/, "=;expires=" + new Date().toUTCString() + ";domain=.example.com;path=/");
});
```

Replace example.com with your domain name.

Comment: If running on localhost simply change domain to `localhost`

Comment: except this deletes ALL your cookies for the domain. Probably not a good idea! Look at @nagesh answer instead. Makes much more sense

Answer (score 3):

I too faced this problem in Chrome. However, in Firefox it worked as expected with the status returned as `connected` when the user had logged in previously.

The root cause of this issue is, on `FB.logout()`, Chrome is not removing the cookie `fblo_<your-app-id>` which is somehow affecting `FB.getLoginStatus()` function to return `unknown`

Fix: On calling `FB.logout()`, you may programmatically delete the cookie `fblo_<your-app-id>`

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
  deleteCookie("fblo_" + fbAppId); // fblo_yourFBAppId. example: fblo_444499089231295
});

function deleteCookie(name) {
  document.cookie = name +'=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue after logout. It appears that `FB.logout()` creates a `fblo_<your-app-id>` cookie that has an expiration date of 1 year and it never goes away, not even after you log in again. It also seems that this particular cookie then obstructs `FB.getLoginStatus()` from returning a proper status in certain cases. Deleting the cookie manually fixes things, but I can't say why it's not being deleted automatically by successful `FB.login()` call