# FB.getLoginStatus() response status is unknown

Tags: facebook, cookies, browser, facebook-javascript-sdk, session-cookies

I have a piece of code which does FB.getLoginStatus() using Facebook JavaScript SDK.
The code work properly on localhost. However when I deploy the code on a different domain the function returns status as 'unknown'(although the browser session is still active). I have set the Facebook App config properly(i.e. domain,site URL, redirect URL).

If I clear the browser history and try, then it works only first time and then returns status 'unknown'.

I get the same behavior in IE, Chrome n Firefox.

Looks like I am messing with some settings. Or is it something to do with cookies n my domain which I am not getting. Any help or pointers ??

Comment: does the browser console tell you something? do you have a test url for us?

Comment: Browser console does not throw any warning or error. Sorry I can not provide URL.

Comment: did u try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889646/fb-getloginstatus-returns-status-unknown?rq=1