# Facebook api response unknown on iOS safari

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, web-applications, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to add a pretty basic facebook connection on my web app :

1. Check if user has already facebook-logged into my webapp
2. If yes, continue to the app
3. If not, show the facebook logging page

The problem appears only in iOS safari. Basically, once in a while **iOS safari users who already logged into the app** arrive with `response.status=='unknown'` from `getLoginStatus()` and when they click the `fb:login-button`, **it just opens and close a window and nothing happens**. They just cant log in anymore.

I first thought about iOS safari pop-up blocker which happens when you call `FB.login()` without a click event but it's not what I'm doing (is it ?). Also, turning off pop-up blocker didn't solve the issue.

The problem could be related to *cache* cause when clearing it allows iOS safari users to log in again. Also the bug doesn't occurs at every connection. But when it does it wont work anymore until logout/clearing cache & cookies.

What I tried :

- Removing cookies when `response == 'unknown'`. Didn't work.
- Calling `FB.logout()` when `response == 'unknown'`. It worked but iOS safari users keeps getting disconnected when it happens.

I (tried to) use the recommended architecture :

**My facebook button**

```
<div class="fbConnect">
 <fb:login-button size="large" scope="public_profile,email,user_friends" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
        Connexion via Facebook
 </fb:login-button>
</div>
```

**facebook.js**

```
function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}

function initFacebook() {
    FB.init({
        appId: myAppId,
        status: true,
        xfbml: true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        version: 'v2.8'
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}

function launchFacebook() {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        initFacebook();
    };
    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}

function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Check if user gave permissions.
      FB.api('/v2.8/me/permissions', function(response) {
        var declined = [];
        for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          if (response.data[i].status == 'declined') {
            declined.push(response.data[i].permission)
          }
        }

        if (declined.length != 0){
          $('#askAgainPermissions').modal();
          console.log('Login modal shown because facebook needs more permission:')
          return;
        } else {
          // Logged into your app and Facebook.
          someFunction();
        }
      });
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
        console.log('Facebook connection NOT AUTHORIZED')
    } else { //response == unknown : !HERE!
        FB.logout(function(response) {
            location.href = 'https://www.mywebapp.com'
            // user is now logged out
        });

    }
}
```

**launch facebook when document ready**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    launchFacebook();
});
```

**How I handle cache in app.yaml**

```
- url: /img
  static_dir: img
  secure: always
  expiration: "0d 10m"

- url: /js
  static_dir: js
  secure: always
  expiration: "0d 10m"

- url: /css
  static_dir: css
  secure: always
  expiration: "0d 10m"

- url: /fonts
  static_dir: fonts
  secure: always
  expiration: "0d 60m"
```

I already did a lot of investigation (e.g. this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889646/fb-getloginstatus-returns-status-unknown)) but could not find any solution.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @gowithefloww, did you find any solution for the above issue? I too ran in to this issue didn't found any solution.

Comment: Didn’t find any solution, sorry!